# The peripheral does not respond to the central in writeRequest (bluetooth)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I set up a function to read a feature, and it works correctly, I send the request from central:

```
func readCharacteristicValue() {
        if let peripheral = connectedPeripheral, let characteristic = targetCharacteristic {
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        }
    }
```

And I process the answer from peripheral:

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveRead request: CBATTRequest) {
        
        //Richiamo comportamenti differenti in base al servizio
        switch request.characteristic.uuid {
            
        case Constants.uuid.AuthService:
                let authenticationInstance = PAuthentication.pAuthentication
                authenticationInstance.responseToReadRequest(request: request, peripheralManager: peripheralManager, clearServiceCharacteristic: clearServiceCharacteristic)
            
            case Constants.uuid.OtherService: print("Other implementation")
            
            default: print("Nothing")
        }
        
    }
```

this is then captured by this function from central:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?){
        //Se qualcosa va storto
        if let error = error {
            print("Error reading characteristic value: \(error)")
        }

        //In base alla caratteristica che sta rispondendo gestisco in maniera differente le risposte
        switch characteristic.uuid {
            
        case Constants.uuid.AuthService:
                let authenticationInstance = CAuthentication.cAuthentication
                authenticationInstance.responceFromReadRequest(characteristic: characteristic, disconnect: disconnect)
            
            default:
                print("Nothing")
        }
    }
```

But when I try to make a write request, I can get to the peripheral, but when it responds I can't see the response, but I don't understand why. This is the function that sends the write request by central:

```
    func writeStringToCharacteristic(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8), let peripheral = connectedPeripheral, let characteristic = targetCharacteristic {
            peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
        }
    }
```

This is the function in peripheral than handle the message:

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
         for request in requests {
             if request.characteristic == characteristic {
                 if let value = request.value {
                     // Esempio: Processa i dati scritti dal Central
                     let receivedString = String(data: value, encoding: .utf8)
                     print("Received data from Central: \(receivedString ?? "")")
                     if (receivedString == "Auth"){
                         
                         var dataToSend:Data?
                         if let name = SharedData.shared.AuthData["name"],
                            let surname = SharedData.shared.AuthData["surname"],
                            let date = SharedData.shared.AuthData["date"] {
                            dataToSend = "\(name), \(surname), \(date)".data(using: .utf8)
                             // Ora puoi utilizzare 'dataToSend' per inviare i dati alla caratteristica Bluetooth
                         } else {
                             print("One or more values are missing")
                         }
                         
                         request.value = dataToSend
                         peripheralManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
                         //NON RIESCO A RECAPITARE LA RISPOSTA DAL CENTRALE
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

From the latter function of the peripheral, I cannot see the message sent to the central. So the central transmits the data to the peripheral but I can't then see the response from the central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peripheral cannot send data to the central in the response to a write request.

The `withResponse` write type requires that the peripheral send a response that the write has been received successfully (the `withResult:.success`), but that is all.  The response does not include any additional data.

For the peripheral to send unsolicited data to the central, it must use Indicate/Notify.

After you respond to the write, you need to use [`updateValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393281-updatevalue) to deliver an updated value to your central. Your central must have previously used [`setNotifyValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue) in order to receive the notification that there is a new value for the characteristic.

Comment: Thank you so much, now work after this tips